# Making objects inside an array using plain javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress theme, using Vegas for a background slider. First of all, with hard coded image path, I made the slider working. Now I'm trying to make it dynamic.

Vegas doesn't support HTML data attributes, so I need to follow [their JS syntax](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/#slides). The syntax of Vegas for declaring slides are like below:

```
$elmt.vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: '/img/slide1.jpg' },
        { src: '/img/slide2.jpg' },
        { src: '/img/slide3.jpg' },
        { src: '/img/slide4.jpg' }
    ]
});
```

The issue is, I'm getting my slider images using PHP query, and getting the exact size of those images using `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. So I'm making an array of those images, and the PHP function returns:

```
Array ( [0] => http://localhost/oneproject/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/slider-image-1200x260.jpg [1] => http://localhost/oneproject/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/disabled-allowance-870x260.jpg )
```

So I'm passing them using `wp_localize_script()` with `json_encode( my_array_func() )`.

In `.js` file I'm getting this:

```
var slider_images = JSON.parse( one.slider_images );
console.log(slider_images);
```

The console outputs the following:
[image: console output]

I'm struggling now, **how can I use this JSON array and use it for Vegas with their given syntax?**

I tried (may be looked like amateurish):

```
$("#my-slider").vegas({
    slides: [

        $.each(slider_images, function( index, value ) {
            //console.log(value);
            { src: "'"+ value +"'" } + ","
        })

    ]
});
```

But it's not loading the images, and the slider is not working.

I also tried making JS Object within an array:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.src = slider_images;
$.each(slider_images, function( index, value ) {
   myObject.src = value;
});
var myString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
console.log(myString);
```

But getting the first one nice, but the second one got double quotes around, and not working.

I'm completely stuck. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this right.

```
var slider_images = JSON.parse( one.slider_images );
console.log(slider_images);
```

What you can do is this.

First, create a new array where you will store the data-compatible objects.

```
var newArray = []
```

Next is loop through each of the slider images and create an object which you will push in the newArray above.

```
slider_images.forEach(function(e, i){
    var newData = {
        src: e
    };
    newArray.push(newData);
});
```

Then finally, use the newly created array in the slider.

```
$("#my-slider").vegas({
    slides: newArray
});
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Works like a charm! +1 now let me learn from this. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad that i'm of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You *do* know that if you use `JSON.stringify(object)` then you have to parse it via `JSON.parse(object)` to 'decode' it? It seems to be your problem.

Comment: That's piece of valuable information. I'm numb at JS. Thanks for the lesson. +1